# Embedded SQL - No output?

Tags: sql, c

I'm doing an assignment learning embedded SQL in C.  The first five queries work just fine, but now I seem to be stuck.  I'm not getting any output on this one, even though it is structured exactly the same as the previous queries.  I'm probably just missing something stupid.  Thoughts?

[ed] The following is the table that SHOULD result from the query.  There are null values in it, and I'm getting an SQL error -305 Null indicator needed.

```
FIRST_NAME MIDDLE_NAME LAST_NAME            BRANCH_NO
---------- ----------- -------------------- ---------
III        -           AAAAA                1000     
KKK        -           BBB                  1000     
MMM        -           CC                   3000     
K          PP          DDD                  3000     
IIIII      SSS         DDDDD                3000     
JJJ        QQ          EEE                  3000     
JJJ        PP          GGG                  1000     
K          -           GGG                  1000     
MEI        -           JIANG                3000     
JASPER     CHIACHUN    WENG                 1000     

  10 record(s) selected.
```

[/ed]

```
void query6()
{
  // SQL Query Definition
  EXEC SQL
    DECLARE c6 CURSOR FOR
      SELECT s.first_name, s.middle_name, s.last_name, b.branch_no
      FROM staff AS s, branch AS b
      WHERE s.allocated_to = b.branch_no AND
            s.allocated_to IN (SELECT branch_no 
                               FROM branch
                               WHERE city = 'HAMILTON')
      ORDER BY s.last_name, s.first_name, s.middle_name;

  // Pretty Output
  printf("\n%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
         "FIRST_NAME","MIDDLE_NAME","LAST_NAME","BRANCH_NO");
  printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
         "----------","-----------","---------","---------");

  // Fetch SQL Result and Print
  EXEC SQL OPEN c6;
  while(1)
  {
    printf("fetch\n");
    EXEC SQL FETCH c6 INTO :sqlBuffer1,
                           :sqlBuffer2,
                           :sqlBuffer3,
                           :sqlBuffer4;
    depad(sqlBuffer1);
    depad(sqlBuffer2);
    depad(sqlBuffer3);
    depad(sqlBuffer4);
    if (SQLCODE!=0) break;
    printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
           sqlBuffer1,sqlBuffer2,sqlBuffer3,sqlBuffer4);
  }
  EXEC SQL CLOSE c6;
  printf("\n");

  return;         
}
```

Comment: Thank you @thkala, I will learn to format my code blocks eventually!

Comment: Just mark your code after you paste it in the edit textbox and click the `{}` button above the box.

Comment: That easy eh?  I'll get it next time then!  LOL

Comment: It seems to me, instead of the `s.allocated_to IN (...)` part of the WHERE clause  you could simply have `b.city = 'HAMILTON'`. It doesn't (shouldn't) change the result, it's just a simplified version of the same condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  Null values need to be addressed explicitly.

```
void query6()
{
  // SQL Query Definition
  EXEC SQL
    DECLARE c6 CURSOR FOR
      SELECT FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,BRANCH_NO
      FROM STAFF,BRANCH
      WHERE STAFF.ALLOCATED_TO=BRANCH.BRANCH_NO AND
            BRANCH.CITY='HAMILTON'
      ORDER BY LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME;

  // Pretty Output
  printf("\n%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
         "FIRST_NAME","MIDDLE_NAME","LAST_NAME","BRANCH_NO");
  printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
         "----------","-----------","---------","---------");

  // Fetch SQL Result and Print
  EXEC SQL OPEN c6;
  while(1)
  {
    EXEC SQL FETCH c6 INTO :sqlBuffer1:b1Null,
                           :sqlBuffer2:b2Null,
                           :sqlBuffer3:b3Null,
                           :sqlBuffer4:b4Null;

    //sqlerr("fetch");
    if (SQLCODE!=0) break;

    if (b1Null == 0)
      depad(sqlBuffer1);
    else strcpy(sqlBuffer1,"--");
    if (b2Null == 0)
      depad(sqlBuffer2);
    else strcpy(sqlBuffer2,"--");
    if (b3Null == 0)
      depad(sqlBuffer3);
    else strcpy(sqlBuffer3,"--");
    if (b4Null == 0)
      depad(sqlBuffer4);
    else strcpy(sqlBuffer4,"--");

    printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
           sqlBuffer1,sqlBuffer2,sqlBuffer3,sqlBuffer4);
  }
  EXEC SQL CLOSE c6;
  printf("\n");

  return;         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems valid but i wold probably write it like so:

```
  SELECT s.first_name, s.middle_name, s.last_name, b.branch_no
  FROM staff AS s, (SELECT branch.branch_no FROM branch WHERE branch.city = 'HAMILTON') AS b
  WHERE s.allocated_to = b.branch_no
  ORDER BY s.last_name, s.first_name, s.middle_name;
```

Comment: Still no output.  The 'fetch' debug statement in the while loop is only hitting once, but it should have 10 records to find.  The query works fine when it's not embedded...

Comment: hav you tried being explicit about the column names (tablename.columnname) in the subquery.. i just gave it a shot in Mysql and i had to do this... Updated my code to reflect this. IT should be noted i do not know or even dabble in C so if its an issue with your C code then someone else will have to chime in, but the SQL i gave you should be fine

Comment: Are you sure you that `s.allocated_to = b.branch_no` is true for all 10 of those records? When using this syntax it will only return results where that matches AS opposed to using a `LEFT JOIN` which would return all results in the parent table regardless of whether they have a `allocated_to` value that matches one of your `branch_no`'s

Comment: Yeah, the previous assignment was doing the SQL queries directly in DB2.  All I'm doing now is copy/pasting the queries into C and trying to get them to work.  Didn't have an issue until this one.

Comment: Also, I went explicit with all the column names and it had no effect.

Comment: Well if it works in your DB client directly then its gotta be something with the C code... unfortunately that is not in my skill set :-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort Prodigitalson, I appreciate it.  Pretty sure it's not the C code itself, I'm thinking there must be some limitation or clause when embedding the code into C that I'm missing...